# Typing text into a search box when using selenium and beautiful soup in Python

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, sendkeys

Usually the below code would work to type information into a search bar, however, it will not let me use .send_keys() on this instance. What do I need to do instead? One thing I noticed is that when I actually click the box the class="hidden appended" line adds a grey "flex" button at the end of the line. Not sure what this means or if it is the reason why the below code won't work.

```
   typetextfirst = driver.find_element_by_id("searchRegistry-text")
   typetextfirst.clear()
   typetextfirst.send_keys(row["Name"])
```

[image]

Comment: Please share a link to that web page. We need to see the input element and it's behavior,

Comment: Absolutely: https://www.bedbathandbeyond.com/store/giftregistry/registry-search-guest?icid=static_st_2acr1_weddingregistry_find_24547

Comment: So you asked for [help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70189497/how-to-use-selenium-to-fill-in-a-text-box) again and finally thrown away all the [efforts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70189497/how-to-use-selenium-to-fill-in-a-text-box/70190005#70190005) like trash.

Comment: Sorry, I did not see your post. I deleted it because the answer I recieved was so simple and I did not know how to close the close as answered. How do I undelete?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are some duplicate elements present in the website with same `id`. Might be that's what creating a problem. I have tried to replicate your scenario and wrote the below code. Do let me know if it works for you as well.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument("start-maximized")

driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
driver.get('https://www.bedbathandbeyond.com/store/giftregistry/registry-search-guest?icid=static_st_2acr1_'
           'weddingregistry_find_24547')

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 30)
action = ActionChains(driver)

# Press Cancel to Close the initial Popup
try:
    wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '(//a[contains(@id,"bx-close-inside-")])[1]'))).click()
except:
    pass

# Perform Search
searchTextbox = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '(//input[@id="searchRegistry-text"])[2]')))
action.move_to_element(searchTextbox).click().send_keys("Hello").perform()

# Click on Search Button
save_Button = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '(//button[text()="Search"])[2]')))
action.move_to_element(save_Button).click()

# Search and Click Type Filter
TypeFilter = wait.until(
    EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//button[@data-locator="search-results-type-filter"]')))
TypeFilter.click()

# Click on Wedding Option
WeddingOption = wait.until(
    EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//button[text()="Wedding"]')))
WeddingOption.click()

# Search and Click Year Filter
YearFilter = wait.until(
    EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//button[@data-locator="search-results-year-filter"]')))
YearFilter.click()

# Select 2021 Filter
Option_2021 = wait.until(
    EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//button[text()="2021"]')))
Option_2021.click()
```

Hope it will resolve your issue. Thanks.

Comment: +1 for great diagnosis. For me at least the solution can be simplified to wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "searchInput")))
driver.find_elements_by_name('q')[1].send_keys("hello")

Comment: So I ran into another challenge. On the next page I was looking to filter Type = Wedding and Year = 2021. Any idea how I can do this? The dropdown will only appear when I mouse over the box, but do not click. Then I have to click the selected dropdown.

Comment: I will edit my Ans to include "Type" and "Year" filter. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try clicking on that element before sending the text, like this:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)

typetextfirst = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "searchRegistry-text")))
typetextfirst.click()
typetextfirst.send_keys(row["Name"])
```

If this still not enough try sending the text with actions:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)
actions = ActionChains(driver)

typetextfirst = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "searchRegistry-text")))

actions.move_to_element(typetextfirst)
actions.click()
actions.send_keys(row["Name"])
actions.perform()
```

Comment: Hmm, neither worked. It errored on the last line actions.perform(): ElementNotInteractableException: Message: element not interactable: [object HTMLInputElement] has no size and location
  (Session info: chrome=91.0.4472.124)

Comment: I think waiting for element clickability should resolve this. See the updated answer

Comment: At least for me, that wait for clickability times out. Also, when I tried to do things at a lower level, I got that it could not be scrolled into view (which is weird, because it is in view)

Comment: I see. Instead of the wait try putting time.sleep of several second. This is not a nice way, but I hope it will help. Let me know it that helped

Comment: No such luck. I did time.sleep(5) between each "action." line. The field that says "(e.g. Jane Doe)" does not even get filled in with any text and am still recieveing the same error on the actions.perform() line

Comment: No, no need to add delays between the action lines. Put delay before getting the element. Since `wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "searchRegistry-text")))` doesn't work do it simply with `typetextfirst = driver.find_element_by_id("searchRegistry-text")`. Put the sleep before this lone